# Multiple option form issue

Tags: php

Hi I have a form with multiple options in php but it doesn't seem to work. I mean the form works in the fact that I can select multiple options, but when I handle posts it doesn't give me anything. Here is my form (it works fine)

```
print"<select name='Category' size='4' multiple='multiple'>\n";
$db = adodbConnect();
$query = "Select * From nodes";
$result = $db -> Execute($query);
while($row=$result->FetchRow())
{
$cat = $row['id'];
$desc =$row['name'];
print "<option value='$cat'>$desc</option>\n";
}
print "</select>\n";
```

here is the issue, I try and use a foreach to retrieve the selected options but it won't give me anything. The mysql stuff is queries work fine and I've used them before but I'm trying to get multiple values and it now doesn't do anything.

```
foreach($_GET['Category'] as $category){
if($category != NULL){
$querytwo = "insert into relationships(id,goingto,data)".
"values(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'$category','')";
$resulttwo = $db -> Execute($querytwo);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i see you are using multiple options selecting so you need to set the name of your select element as this name='Category[]'

try to apply this change and tell me the result :)

Comment: @user1902588 : Hello But why you are using $_GET instead of $_POST inside the code of retrieving options selected with applying the change of the name of your select element as i mentioned above :)

Try this and tell me the result :)

Comment: For nothing ! But please mark my answer as correct one and tell me if you want any adittional help ! i am just here :)